# wrong double values in csv file

Tags: c++, csv, ofstream

I'm trying to summarize the results of my algorihtm in a CSV-file. However some values get lost. For example 0.375 is saved as 375 and 0,125 is saved as 125.

```
    if (options[SUMMARY]) {
        std::ofstream summary(options[SUMMARY].arg);
        summary << "Runtime" << ";" << runtime << std::endl;
        for (auto u : results) {
                  for (auto v : u.second) {
                    if (measures.size() == 0) {
                    summary << v.first << ";" << v.second.second << std::endl;
                } else if (measures.size() == 1) {
                    summary << v.first << ";"
                            << (measures[0])->getQuality(v.second.first) 
                                        << std::endl;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Do anyone have some explanation or ideas to overtake this issue?

Comment: Can you post a couple of lines of your CSV file?

Comment: Are you sure it is 0.375 (0 POINT 375) and not 0,375. C++ reads floating point numbers as floating point numbers only if the have a POINT and not a COMMA.

Comment: Make sure all float's are written with ".". You're inconsistent now, mentioning 0.375 and 0,125...

Comment: all floats have a point. :)

Comment: Some values from my csv : 
Runtime 11721 ;  
5740 0.777778;  
5745 1 ;           
2586 0.333333;  
5073 0.32143 ;                   
8532 1125;

Values are expected to range from 0 to 1

Comment: What is the return type of getQuality(v.second.first), maybe int? Do you know if your problems appear for values printed with measures.size() == 0, or with 1?

Comment: it returns a double.when i plot the results in the console the problem doesn't occur. up to now everything seems to be right with measures.size() == 0

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is related to `locale` - the settings on your machine may indicate that a "," is the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

RFC-4180 says that CSV implementations may differ in their interpretation of the decimal separator (among other things). Try imbuing a locale onto the stream where  `.` is classified as a decimal separator.

```
std::ofstream summary(options[SUMMARY].arg);
summary.imbue(std::locale(summary.getloc(), new std::numpunct<char>));
```